# Easier and much easier trouble

Tags: comparative-degree

I read an article on [ThinkProgress](http://thinkprogress.org/economy/2015/01/06/3608364/dynamic-scoring/). Its heading is:

> The Republicans’ Sneaky Plan To Make It ***Much Easier*** To Pass Massive Tax Cuts For The Rich

I know the term 'easier' that means 'more easy'. I know the 'easiest', which is a superlative form of 'easy'. But, "much easier" confuses me.

Which kind of usage is this?

Comment: 'Much easier' is a very common use; or you want to convey something else?

Comment: @MaulikV I am confused with the usage of "much" with countable things also, is "much easy" possible?

Answer (score 1):

*Much* simply indicates that it is not a little bit easier, but a lot. That doesn't mean it has to be the easiest.

1 billion dollars is *much more* than I have, but is is not *the most* money anyone can have.

A mouse is *larger* than an ant, a rat is *a bit larger* than a mouse, but an elephant is *much larger* than a rat. Yet, an elephant is not *the largest* animal that exists.

So something can be easier than something else; it can be only *a bit easier*, meaning it is almost as difficult, or it can be *much easier*, meaning that the difference in easiness is quite large. Still it may not be the easiest!

---

You asked about *much easy* in your comments: that is **not** possible.

We use *very* with standard adjectives:

> He is very fast.
>   The book is very boring.

We use *much* with comparatives:

> The other guy is much faster.
>   The the telephone guide is much more boring than that book.

With the superlative we normally don't use any amplification (superlative means it is the maximum already!) but in some cases, people do use *very* with superlatives:

> Send me the very best developer you have!

Comment: Can you rewrite the answer? Please see my comment.

Comment: @RuchirM Rewriting it seems a bit much, if it helps I can **add** something. But I am not sure what you mean with _countable_ things. _Easy_ is not a noun, it is not countable. _Much easy_ is certainly not correct, that would be _very easy_. What exactly is your extra question?

Comment: I was getting confused with countable (facts here) and 'much', and I wondered if 'much easier' is possible, why not  'much easy'? I know more easy is not good to write, instead we write easier.

Comment: I am still confused where you found anything countable. What _facts_ are you talking about? There are no _facts_ mentioned anywhere on this complete page except in your comment. Can you please specify in what way (you think) _countable_ has anything to do with your question?

Comment: I made a mistake. I thought 'tax cuts' is what 'much easier' is applied to. I was confused 'much' applying to 'easier' or 'tax cut!' It's clear from your answer anyway. And, what about 'much easy'? Why isn't it possible?

Comment: I see :) No, indeed, _much_ only refers to _easier_. The countable _tax cuts_ would take _many_ if we would want to say there are a lot of them. I hope my edit is a bit helpful — I don;t have an answer for _why_ very / much are used like this, but they just _are_ :)